# floor function integral and GCD?

Tags: calculus, integration

please can you help me evaluate this integral?

$$\int_0^{1}\lfloor ax\rfloor \lfloor bx\rfloor dx$$

where $$GCD(a,b)=1$$

$$a\in\Bbb Z ,b\in\Bbb Z$$

Comment: What does PGCD mean?

Comment: sorry it is the GCD

Comment: Are a and b integers or positive real no. or something else?

Comment: $a\in\Bbb Z ,b\in\Bbb Z$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Indicating the floor and fractional part of $x$ as
$$x = \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  + \left\{ x \right\}$$

since for every real $c \ne 0$ we have
$$
\int {\left\lfloor {cx} \right\rfloor dx}  = \frac{1}
{c}\int {\left\lfloor {cx} \right\rfloor d\left( {cx} \right)}  = \frac{1}
{c}\left( \begin{gathered}
  \left\lfloor {cx} \right\rfloor  \\ 
  2 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) + \frac{1}
{c}\left\lfloor {cx} \right\rfloor \left\{ {cx} \right\}
$$
and
$$
\frac{d}
{{d\,x}}\left\lfloor {cx} \right\rfloor  = \delta _{\,\left\{ {cx} \right\}} 
$$
then we can write, integrating by parts
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\begin{gathered}
  \int_{x\, = \,0}^{\;1} {\left\lfloor {ax} \right\rfloor \left\lfloor {bx} \right\rfloor dx} \quad \left| {\;0 \ne a,b\; \in \;\;\mathbb{R}\,} \right.\quad  =  \hfill \\
   = \left. {\left( {\frac{1}
{a}\left( {\left( \begin{gathered}
  \left\lfloor {ax} \right\rfloor  \\ 
  2 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) + \left\lfloor {ax} \right\rfloor \left\{ {ax} \right\}} \right)\left\lfloor {bx} \right\rfloor } \right)} \right|_{x\, = \,0}^{\;1}  - \frac{1}
{a}\int_{x\, = \,0}^{\;1} {\left( {\left( \begin{gathered}
  \left\lfloor {ax} \right\rfloor  \\ 
  2 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) + \left\lfloor {ax} \right\rfloor \left\{ {ax} \right\}} \right)\delta _{\,\left\{ {b\,x} \right\}} dx}  =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{{\left\lfloor a \right\rfloor }}
{a}\left( {\frac{{\left\lfloor a \right\rfloor  - 1}}
{2} + \left\{ a \right\}} \right)\left\lfloor b \right\rfloor  - \frac{1}
{{2a}}\int_{x\, = \,0}^{\;1} {\left\lfloor {ax} \right\rfloor \left( {\left\lfloor {ax} \right\rfloor  - 1 + 2\left\{ {ax} \right\}} \right)\delta _{\,\left\{ {b\,x} \right\}} dx}  =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{{\left\lfloor a \right\rfloor \left\lfloor b \right\rfloor }}
{{2a}}\left( {\left\lfloor a \right\rfloor  - 1 + 2\left\{ a \right\}} \right) - \frac{1}
{{2a}}\sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,\left\lfloor b \right\rfloor } {\left\lfloor {\frac{a}
{b}k} \right\rfloor \left( {\left\lfloor {\frac{a}
{b}k} \right\rfloor  - 1 + 2\left\{ {\frac{a}
{b}k} \right\}} \right)}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
}$$
or exchanging $a$ with $b$.

Answer (score -1):

Plug in two numbers for a start: say $a=3$, $b=7$.

You might see that you have a function that looks like steps with widths of thirds and sevenths, where the $gcd(a,b)=1$ means that there is no overlap of the steps for all $x\in[0,1]$.

As such, due to linearity of the integral you can split it to a sum of integrals such that for each term you integrate over a constant function.

Now describe in detail the value of the constant function at each unique step, and the corresponding limits of integration.

Can you take it from here?